# Hypothesis Testing For Two Sample Mean Proportion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, two-sample

We've two samples of size `n_1` and `n_2` from two different normally distributed populations. We don't know their population means but we know their population variances as `(σ_1)^2` and `(σ_2)^2`.

Null hypothesis is,

```
H_0: μ_1 = μ_2 / 2
```

and alternative hypothesis is,

```
H_1: μ_1 < μ_2 / 2
```

How should we proceed in this hypothesis testing procedure? Which statistic model we should use?

Thanks!

Comment: Just scale all the observations in the second sample by 0.5 and run the usual one-sided, 2 sample T-test with unequal variance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by scaling the observations? Also, since we know population variances, can't we use 2 sample Z-test, why do we need to use T-test? @AdamO

Comment: Scaling: multiplying by a scalar. e.g. a duration in years can be converted to days by scaling by 365.25

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If everything is independent, you can construct a sensible linear combination of the data which is normally distributed with known population variance and which would have population mean $0$ when the null hypothesis is true

The alternative hypothesis would then point at which tail(s) to look at